# Solve for matrix in squared formula

Tags: matrices

Assuming $b$ is a scalar, $v$ a vector and $S$ is a symmetric matrix. How do can I express $S$ in terms of $b$ and $v$ if

$$
b = v^T\cdot S^{-1}\cdot v
$$

Note that $b$ and $v$ are given and non-zero.

Comment: $b$ will be a scalar, not a vector. Also, there will be many, many $S$.

Comment: In general you can't. Just take $b=v=0$. Then $S$ is arbitary.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: $b$ and $v$ are given. Is this only possible numerically/approximately? Or are there multiple $S$ that are valid?

Comment: $b$ and $v$ are given. Yes, I know. But it might be given that $v=0$. This already shows you the problem in your question "how can I express $S$". What $S$? It will not be unique in general.

Comment: @Make42, if you want a nonzero $S$, I would consider the variational approach: $|| v^{T} \cdot S \cdot v - b||^2 \rightarrow_{S} \min$.  Here $|| \cdot ||$ denotes the norm induced by your dot product.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I added the information that S is symmetric and that we actually discuss the inverse.

Comment: $S$ is a matrix with $n^2$ entries. Essentially you have $n^2$ unknowns (or given that it is symmetric, $n(n+1)/2$ unknowns) and only one equation. For large $n$ that is a seriously underspecified system of simultaneous equations....